# JS. Функция для изменения ширины и высоты Diva

Tags: javascript

В поля(инпуты) вводится высота и ширина, и блок должен тут же менять ширину и высоту, но оставаться в нужных пределах (250 на 250).

То есть, если заданы параметры 250 - 200, то блок будет 250px на 200px.
Если заданы параметры 500 на 100, то блок будет 250px на 50px (все пропорции уменьшатся в 2 раза, чтобы поместиться).

Написал код, но он не работает, при некоторых значениях блок явно вылазит за пределы. Я не могу понять в чем дело.

Например когда вводишь значение 999 на 250 - все окей (блок становится 250 на 65)
А когда 1000 на 250 - все летит к....

```js
function onlinechanger(){

var lenghtpaper = $('#lenghtpaper').val();
var tollpaper = $('#tollpaper').val();

document.getElementById('lengthres').innerHTML = lenghtpaper;
document.getElementById('tollres').innerHTML = tollpaper;

if (lenghtpaper > 250 || tollpaper > 250) {
 var chang = lenghtpaper > tollpaper ? lenghtpaper : tollpaper;
 var coef = 250 / chang;
 lenghtpaper = Math.round(lenghtpaper*coef);
 tollpaper = Math.round(tollpaper*coef);
}

$("#viziblock").css({'width': lenghtpaper, 'height' : tollpaper});

}
```

```css
#viziblock {background: #fff; border: 1px solid #000; width: 250px; height: 250px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="generalcalc">
       <form onsubmit="return false;">
         <div class="income">
    <div>Длина </div>
              <input id="lenghtpaper" type="number" oninput="onlinechanger()" value="250">
    <div>Высота </div>
              <input id="tollpaper" type="number" oninput="onlinechanger()" value="250">
            </div>
          
            <div class="resultraschet">Результаты расчета</div>
            <div class="resume">
    <div class="lengthres">Длина: <output id="lengthres"></output> </div>
    <div class="tollres">Высота: <output id="tollres"></output></div>
            </div>
   
   <div id="viziblock"></div>

    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема [в том, что](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

```js
console.log("250" > "1000") // true
```

Приведите длину и высоту к числу, прежде чем их сравнивать:

```js
function onlinechanger(){
  var lenghtpaper = parseInt($('#lenghtpaper').val());
  var tollpaper = parseInt($('#tollpaper').val());

  document.getElementById('lengthres').innerHTML = lenghtpaper;
  document.getElementById('tollres').innerHTML = tollpaper;

  if (lenghtpaper > 250 || tollpaper > 250) {
    var chang = lenghtpaper > tollpaper ? lenghtpaper : tollpaper;
    var coef = 250 / chang;
    lenghtpaper = Math.round(lenghtpaper*coef);
    tollpaper = Math.round(tollpaper*coef);
  }

  $("#viziblock").css({'width': lenghtpaper, 'height' : tollpaper});

}
```

```css
#viziblock {background: #fff; border: 1px solid #000; width: 250px; height: 250px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="generalcalc">
   <form onsubmit="return false;">
     <div class="income">
      <div>Длина </div>
          <input id="lenghtpaper" type="number" oninput="onlinechanger()" value="250">
      <div>Высота </div>
          <input id="tollpaper" type="number" oninput="onlinechanger()" value="250">
     </div>

     <div class="resultraschet">Результаты расчета</div>
     <div class="resume">
      <div class="lengthres">Длина: <output id="lengthres"></output> </div>
      <div class="tollres">Высота: <output id="tollres"></output></div>
     </div>

  <div id="viziblock"></div>
</form>
</div>
```